# How to implement my serialization method for it to be polymorhic and extendable

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0

Currently all my objects contain save and load methods. These methods are basically creating an xml document. Inner objects are serialized using their respective save methods (sometimes its interfaces). Now I want sometimes to do different serialization in some of my objects.
So basically I want to be able to go from one version of serialization to another.

One way is to seperate the serialization logic from the class itself into a separate class (kind of like microsoft's xmlserializer) and thus extending functionality, but then I have a problem when an object's type is unknown to me because its a base class or interface.

Is there another, better way (other than using XmlSerializer or DataContractSerializer)?

Thanks,
Pavel

Comment: What, *specifically* is the issue when the base type is unknown?

Comment: when the type is unknown and the serializtion performed in outer class - this class may not know all the members to serialize.

Comment: Well, `XmlSerializer` doesn't "know" all the members to serialize - it can, however, deduce them using a combination of reflection and instruction (typically via attributes, but can also be through code). To give a sensible answer, I'm trying to understand the problems you are currently having - for example, what *doesn't* work here if you just used `new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType())` ?

Comment: I am not using XmlSerializer. Currently each object knows its own structure and is able to serialize himself. Now I want to add another serialization but I don't want to add a method called "save2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (comments), you have an existing Save(...) method that each implementation provides - and don't want to add a Save2(...) for a different layout.

In that case, I would simply add whatever defines the new format as a parameter. If it could involve multiple things (maybe a version number and a format), I would write a class such as `SerializationContext` with those things as properties, and modify the existing saves to take this, i.e.

```
Save(..., SerializationContext ctx)
```

Any existing code will probably ignore `ctx` completely, but as necessary your classes can elect to check `ctx.Version` or `ctx.Format` etc, to behave appropriately. You also have the ability to add additional things to `SerializationContext` at a later date if required.

Comment: Thank you. Yes you understand correctly. I was hoping to avoid checking the version because its kind of like adding save2 just in the same block. I am going to check again if either the strategy or visitor design patterns can be of use to me.